# Change background color of Spinner popup

Tags: android, android-spinner

I need to change the color of the spinner popup.
Here is what I have attempted till now:
**java code:**

```
ArrayAdapter<Integer> adapter_year = new ArrayAdapter<Integer>(this, R.drawable.custom_spinner_holidays, year);
adapter_year.setDropDownViewResource(R.layout.customize_spinner);
```

**custom_spinner_holidays.xml**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<TextView xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:id="@android:id/text1"
    style="@drawable/custom_spinner"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:singleLine="true"
    android:textColor="@android:color/white" />
```

**customize_spinner.xml**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:orientation="vertical" >

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/spinnertext"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:background="#0193DE"
        android:textColor="#FFFFFF"
        android:textSize="18sp" />

</LinearLayout>
```

But it doesn't work. I get error when I click on the spinner.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/24878267/android-change-custom-spinners-dropdownitem-style

Comment: Hope this works...http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12606660/how-can-i-change-the-background-color-of-a-spinner-popup

Answer (score 21, accepted):

You are making things complicated! Just add this to your main spinner xml

```
android:popupBackground="#yourcolor"
```

and change your java code as:

```
adapter_year.setDropDownViewResource(android.R.layout.simple_spinner_dropdown_item);
```